# Let $n > 1$ and $m$ and $ r$ be positive integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n > 1$ and $m,r$ be positive integers.

a)Prove that if $r|m$ then $n^r −1 | n^m −1$.

b)Prove that if $n^r −1|n^m −1$ then $r|m$. (Hint: write $m=qr+d$ and show that $d = 0$).

Comment: You should show some effort in order for people to want to help.

Answer (score 1):

Part $a)$ is quite easy as you use: $n^{rd} - 1 = (n^r - 1)((n^{r})^{d-1} + (n^{r})^{d-2}+\cdots + 1)$ .

For part $b)$ write $m = rq + d$. Thus $n^m -1  = n^d(n^{rq}-1) + n^d-1$
. Thus $n^r - 1 \mid n^m - 1\implies n^r - 1 \mid n^d - 1\implies n^d - 1 = 0$ since $d < r \implies n^d - 1 < n^r - 1$. Thus $d = 0$, and $r \mid m$.